# Uncaght typerror de JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Es una funcion simple que quiero que invierta la cadena que le introduzco como argumento. Todo funciona bien, salvo que cuando quiero reemplazar la "," que separa cada elemento de la cadena, da este error:

> ejercicio-13.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only
> property '1' of string 'a,n,a,i,r,A'
> at invertir (ejercicio-13.js:26)
> at ejercicio-13.js:33

Aqui está el algoritmo.

```js
let palabra = prompt("Ingresa la palabra: ");
    
    function invertir(palabra){
        var lista = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
            lista.push(palabra[i]);
        }
        lista.reverse()
        lista = lista.join()
        for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            if(lista[i] == ","){
                lista[i] = "";//Aqui da error
                console.log(lista[i])
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
    
    console.log(invertir(palabra));
```

Comment: Probé tu código y funciona bien ¿Cuál palabra pruebas cuando da error?

Comment: No puedes cambiar la letra de una cadena porque las cadenas en javascript son inmutables. Pero incluso si pudieras, tu algoritmo fallaría. Imagina que te pase la cadena "Esto, fallará". No vas a poder capturar la coma porque tu algoritmo elimina todas las comas. Checa la alternativa que te doy en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

El error te lo da porque las cadenas en Javascript son **inmutables**. No puedes cambiar el valor de una letra indexando.

Ahórrate remplazar la coma  y eliminarás el error y hasta tu código se hará más corto. Simplemente utiliza `join('')` y te unirá la cadena sin comas.

```js
let palabra = prompt("Ingresa la palabra: ");
    
    function invertir(palabra){
        var lista = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
            lista.push(palabra[i]);
        }
        lista.reverse()
        lista = lista.join('')
        return lista;
    }
    
    console.log(invertir(palabra));
```

Incluso puedes reducirlo a esto:

```js
let palabra = prompt("Ingresa la palabra: ");
    
    function invertir(palabra){
      return palabra.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
    
    console.log(invertir(palabra));
```